# JSON serialization if there is blank or null from API

Tags: json, swift

Hi I am using an API to call from a server a list of requirements called availability requirements before an app goes online. However, when there availability requirements has a null, it crashes the app.

I have attempted to to write the code down below with my fix. . There may be other ways to write this but I was hoping to use just JSON serialization. I have checked the forums and most have older code.

```
    let rquirements = company.availabilityRequirements
    if rquirements != nil {
        let data = rquirements?.data(using: .utf8)!
        do {
            if let jsonArray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options : .allowFragments) as? [Dictionary<String,Any>]
            {
                print(jsonArray) //using the json here 
                for requirements in jsonArray {
                    let hist = AvailabilityRequirements(data: requirements)
                    availabitlityReqirements.append(hist)
                }
            } else { //where our error happens if nil
                print("Bad JSON Cannot Convert Value")
                return
            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)
            return
        }

        for requirement in availabitlityReqirements {
            if requirement.required == 1{
                requirementItems.append(requirement.displayName)

            }
        }
```

I am trying to fix the swift error, if the there is a blank or missing data from availability requirements. I was hoping if anything I did solved the problem, otherwise I was wondering if someone can help me not crash my app if I get null. Thanks

Comment: What's `AvailabilityRequirements(data:)`?

Comment: It’s an NSobject which contains a strict with let’s for name, display name, required and type.

Comment: So in that method there is a line causing the crash because of the null, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `try?` to avoid error. Whole code can be:

```
if let rquirements = company.availabilityRequirements, 
    let data = rquirements.data(using: .utf8) {

    do {
        if let jsonArray = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options : .allowFragments) as? [String: Any] {
            print(jsonArray) 

            for requirements in jsonArray {
                let hist = AvailabilityRequirements(data: requirements)
                availabitlityReqirements.append(hist)
            }
        }

    } catch let error as Error {
        print(error)
        return
    }

    for requirement in availabitlityReqirements {
        if requirement.required == 1 {
            requirementItems.append(requirement.displayName)
        }
    }

}
```